# how to pass the current document id in Lotus Notes to a Lotus Script/Java agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to customize Lotus Notes form by calling a agent on document submit.
How do I pass the document id of the current document(new calendar item/new mail etc) to the java agent?Can this be done using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can set up an agent to run automatically on all new and modified documents in a database. If you do that, then you don't have to pass anything, as the agent will get a reference to the new/modified document via the NotesDocument.UnprocessedDocuments property.

But secondly, if you're using the Javascript NotesAgent.runOnServer() method to run your agent, that method takes a noteid as an argument.  You can access the noteid via the NotesDocument.getNoteID() method and just pass it as the argument.

Comment: and if the server is new enough, then there is even a NotesAgent.runWithDocumentContext to directly give the document to the agent, where it can be read using NotesSession.DocumentContext